# What is the difference between [:] and [] in python?

Tags: python

I'm submitting the answer in leetcode(27).I need to get back the correct list and length. When I plan to do this.

**Input:
[3,2,2,3]
3**

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        if not nums:
            return 0
        nums = [i for i in nums if val != i]
        return len(nums)

Output:       [3,2]
Expected:     [2,2]
```

Clearly my answer is wrong.  But when I write it this way, the solution is correct.

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        if not nums:
            return 0
        nums[:] = [i for i in nums if val != i]
        return len(nums)

Output:       [2,2]
Expected:     [2,2]
```

I don't understand the difference between these two ways. Why do I get two different lists?

Answer (score 0):

nums[:] change the original nums inplace.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: when down vote, please shout some reason...